# Is it necessary to switch to the Swing thread from an application's main method?

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety

In my `main(String[] args)` method I have naught but a call to `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` to run a `main1` method on the Swing thread. I always assumed I needed this for thread safety. I've been told that it isn't necessary because the first thread to do any GUI code *becomes* the GUI thread. Or to put it another way, you can only use Swing from one thread, but it doesn't matter which one. But I can't find a source for this and I'd like to be certain.

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing: Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: The Swing documentation states that this is what should be done. I'd tend to believe it, because while ignoring the advice might work 99.9% of the time, it has a chance of failing sometime, and according to the laws of the universe, this failure will occur only when you're demonstrating your program to your biggest customer or your boss.

Comment: Point of pedantry: It's an AWT thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have been told is false. The `main` method will initially be called by the main thread. All GUI related activity must be performed on a completely separate thread called the *Event Dispatch Thread*. The main thread **does not** become the EDT.

A nice example to see what I'm talking about:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Thread main = Thread.currentThread();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread edt = Thread.currentThread();

                System.out.println(main);
                System.out.println(edt);
                System.out.println(main.equals(edt));
            }
        });
    }
}
```